# I'm trying to make something that reloads a tab as a prank for my friend but it does not reload

Tags: bookmarklet

I'm trying to make it crash chrome but it does not seem to work can someone see what I did wrong with my code and fix it please?

javascript:(document.reload.while)()

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what your trying to ask but bookmarklets (to my knowledge) stop when you refresh, even if you are refreshing with a bookmarklet

you can use `javascript:location.reload();` to refresh the page, but that will stop the script so you cant wrap it in a `setInterval()`